# Proper/efficient way to apply multidimensional data to less-dimensional function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

How do I apply a more-dimension data to less-dimension function?

Let's say I have numpy array of shape (5, 100, 300). I calculate mean on given axis

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr
>>> data = np.zeros((5, 100, 300))
>>> means = data.mean(axis=1)
>>> means.shape
(5, 300)
```

I want to calculate pearson correlation between mean and each element. I tried:

```
q = pearsonr(data, means)
```

witch obviously did not work. So I tried to add a loop hoping it will work like many other numpy functions and apply function along axis (despite missing `axis` argument):

```
>>> pearson = np.empty((5, 100, 2))
>>> for index in range(100):
        pearson[:, index] = pearsonr(data[:, index], means)
```

and got

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Obvious workaround was to add another loop:

```
>>> for index in range(data.shape[0]):
        for subindex in range(data.shape[1]):   
            pearson[index, subindex] = pearsonr(data[index, subindex], means[index])
```

which worked well. But it seems like "not a numpy way". And the actual dataset I use has more dimensions, which means more nested loops. Is there any more efficient way to get what I want?

Comment: What arguments does `pearsonr` take?  Dimensions, etc?

Comment: It takes two 1-dimentional arrays

Comment: Not really.  Either you eliminate redundant calculations, or you shove loops into compiled code.  There are tricks that make generating all the indices easier, but as long as you have to call the function once for each row (last dimension array of size 300), you won't gain any speed.

Comment: A quick read of `pearsonr` suggests that it should be possible to replicate in a way that handles (k,m,n) and (k,n) inputs, especially if you just want `r` and not `prob`.

Comment: Well, if there are no other ways to speed up calculation -> make an answer and i'll accept it

(It's not the case as I want both `r` and `prob` )